# Why is Bitwise OR not working in my Jest test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, bit-manipulation, babeljs

I am trying to write a function that essentially concats an integer array into an integer. The integer will never be larger than 64 bits. For example, by providing the code with [0xa5, 0x71], the expected return value is 0xa571.

When I just do a printline statement, it seems to work correctly

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (0x2f << 8) | 0xa1;
```

The above code returns 12193, which is the same as 0x2fa1. This is an expected result.

I wrote a jest unit test for my function which is supposed to do this automatically

From Extract.js:

```js
const BYTE_SIZE = 8;

/**
 * Turns an Int8Array into an integer. This is done by pretending the array is one integer. In other words,
 * It would be able change [0x2f, 0xa7] into 0x2fa7
 * @param {Int8Array} a The array to convert into the single integer
 * @return {number} the new single integer
 */
export function convertArrayIntoInt(a) {
    let v = a[0];
    for(let i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        v = (v << BYTE_SIZE) | a[i];
    }
    return v;
}
```

From extract.test.js

```js
test("ensures that Int8arrays are turned into integers correctly", () => {
    let arr = Int8Array.from([0x2f, 0xa1]);
    let expected = 0x2fa1;
    expect(Extract.convertArrayIntoInt(arr)).toBe(expected);
});
```

This returns -95 which is 0xffa1.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is?

Comment: The main person who can help you here, is you.`Int8Array.from([0x2f, 0xa1]);` is `[ 47, -95 ]`, so: look at your `convertArrayIntoInt` code: what does it do on that input? Seriously, take a pen an paper, and just run through the few lines of code you wrote, it'll take about a minute but will be so much more valuable than someone here telling you what's wrong. Because -95 is *absolutely* the correct answer. As a hint, though, "what are you using bitwise OR for, and can bitwise OR be used for that?".

Comment: I just used a debugger and realized that 0xa1 is actually -95 in signed 2s complement whis is 0xffa1. I just dont understand why it is showing up like that.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use an `Uint8Array`?